# Proving that $P$ and $Q$ are symmetric in the line $XY$.

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral with diagonals intersecting at $T$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the projections of $T$ onto $AB$ and $CD$ respectively. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the mid-points of $AD$ and $BC$ respectively.

[image]

I am required to prove that $P$ and $Q$ are symmetric in the line $XY$, but I have absolutely no idea where to begin here. All that comes to mind is that I could try to prove that the midpoint of $PQ$ lies on the line $XY$, but this does not seem like it would lead to anything.

Comment: One way to prove this would be using algrebra, or more specifically to deal with some possibly big polynomials using a computer algebra system. Without loss of generality, your circle is the unit circle and none of your points is $(-1,0)$. Then you can represent your points using the tangent half-angle substitution as homogeneous coordinates $(1-a^2,2a,1+a^2)$ and similar for $b,c,d$, and compute everything else from that. But intermediate results might become big, and if this problem was given to you by some educator they probably had something else in mind.

Comment: I noticed that you accepted an answer to this question, but dit not upvote. If there is something that can be improved, then you should let *timon92* know. Please also read: [Why is voting important?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a point such that $\angle DAZ = \angle ZDA = \angle PAT$ and $Z$, $T$ lie on different sides of the line $AD$. Then $\triangle PAT \sim \triangle XAZ$, therefore $$\frac{PA}{XA} = \frac{TA}{ZA}.$$ Moreover $$\angle PAX = \angle PAT + \angle TAX = \angle XAZ + \angle TAX = \angle TAZ.$$ Using SAS we conclude that $\triangle PAX \sim \triangle TAZ$. In particular $$\frac{XP}{ZT} = \frac{PA}{TA}.$$
Analogously $$\frac{XQ}{ZT}=\frac{QD}{TD}.$$
However $\triangle PAT \sim \triangle QDT$ so $$\frac{PA}{TA}=\frac{QD}{TD}.$$
Combining these three equalities we get $$\frac{XP}{ZT}=\frac{PA}{TA}=\frac{QD}{TD}=\frac{XQ}{ZT},$$ therefore $XP=XQ$.

We can prove in a similar way that $YP=YQ$. Therefore $P,Q$ are symmetric with respect to $XY$.